# Does anyone have bluetooth working on Dell 7559 (intel 3165 ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: bluetooth, intel, iwlwifi

My bluetooth worked in 15.10 using one of the earlier kernels (4.3?) but I upgraded for better skylake support and my bluetooth no longer works.  I can detect a device but it will not connect and play sound through the device.  I am now on kernel 4.4 in ubuntu 16.04.  Anyone else have bluetooth working on this intel card? I have iwlwifi-16 firmware..

Using blueman it issues this error message:

```
Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available
```

Comment: I think you need to file a bug report against package Linux, some info [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1011078) on filing bug reports

Comment: same problem here. I have a fresh xubuntu 16.04  installation on my dell latitude e6410 laptop. Trying to connect to JBL Charge3 speaker. The device was paired, but i can connect only to serial port. When Try to connect to audio sink or headset I get Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available. Did you solve it?